# Jboss 7.1 EJB3 with Apache FTPClient

Tags: jboss, ftp, ejb-3.0

I have deployed EJB3 with Apache FTPClient File upload in  Jboss 7 its working fine,
But the same code is not working in Jboss 7.1, I am not getting exception from application, but its hanging while enter into FTP Part. Finally getting following error in Jboss console.

[com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a00000a:19692d93:52396a3c:6c in state  RUN

13:06:34,848 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a00000a:19692d93:52396a3c:6c invoked while multiple threads active within it.

13:06:34,848 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0a00000a:19692d93:52396a3c:6c aborting with 1 threads active!

13:06:34,878 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff0a00000a:19692d93:52396a3c:6c

How we can do FtpClient in Jboss 7.1 EJB3,  please share your ideas.

Application Flow   ------>Stateless Session Bean ----------> DAO class --------->FTPClient.

Thanks and Regards

J Babu

babuj03@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error because of FTP server is not responding in time for jboss7.1. 
so I got that exception, after repair proxy and fire wall,
its working fine in Jboss7.1.